# Example of xsd:unique with multiple concatenated fields?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been tasked with creating a schema for my testing framework that verifies that one attribute and one element come together and form one unique pair. I'll explain this a little better after showing you the example XML segment.

```
  <Test name="testName" dll="testDLL" active="true" >
    <model cad_sys="targetSystem" dir="directory">
      <name>modelName</name>
    </model>
  </Test>
```

In this scenario, the two items we are interested in look at are the testName, and the modelName. Ideally here's the flow of test cases

- testName = "Test1", modelName = "Model1" - is Fine
- testName = "Test1", modelName = "Model2" - is Fine
- testName = "Test2", modelName = "Model1" - is Fine
- testName = "Test1", modelName = "Model1" - Would raise the flag as a duplicate

Now, I've tried playing around with this and have learned quite a bit about schemas that I didn't know, but I'm coming up a bit stumped as to how to solve this part of it.

If any of you have any guidance, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Are you saying that `Test/@name` concatenated with `Test/model/name` must be unique, or that their numeric suffixes cannot match?

Comment: @kjhughes - You're correct. Test/@name concatenated with Test/model/name should be unique. The way our framework reports tests is by using the two concatenated as the file name. I've found out that it has been overwriting results because some people haven't been as careful with the naming of their tests/models and I've decided to introduce the schema to address it. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xs:unique` and with multiple `xs:fields` to constrain their concatenation to be a unique combination:

```
    <xs:unique name="testNameModelNameUnique">
      <xs:selector xpath="Test"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/> 
      <xs:field xpath="model/name"/>
    </xs:unique>
```

Here `xs:unique` in an XSD that'll validate your XML and enforce your constraint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Tests">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Test" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="testNameModelNameUnique">
      <xs:selector xpath="Test"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/> 
      <xs:field xpath="model/name"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Test">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="model">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="cad_sys" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="dir" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="active"  type="xs:boolean"/>
      <xs:attribute name="dll" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```